# Moving platform in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make a platform that moves up when the player enters it.

**MovingPlatform.cs**

```
public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 newPosition;
       
    void Start()
    {
       newPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 5, transform.position.z);
      
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPosition, 4 * Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the platform moves up only a little and without the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why the platform moves only once

The reason, the platform moves only once is due to `OnTriggerEnter` getting called upon entering the trigger not staying inside it. If you want it to get called constantly, while inside it, use `OnTriggerStay` instead or assign a boolean value inside `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` methods and change your position inside an `Update`/`FixedUpdate`.

## Why the platform moves without the player

Regarding the platform moving without the player, I'm assuming that the player is a physics object and you expect them to be pushed by it. Potential reasons for that happening:

- You are moving the platform too fast
- You are moving the platform outside the physics loop
- The platform and/or player doesn't have a collider (Trigger colliders do not collide)

## Potential solution

It uses `OnCollisionEnter` instead of the `OnTriggerEnter` since it seemed to be more appropriate in this case (Make sure to have a non-trigger collider, if you gonna use it).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 targetPosition = default;

    private bool touchingPlayer = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetPosition = new Vector3(
            transform.position.x,
            transform.position.y + 5f,
            transform.position.z);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (touchingPlayer)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                transform.position,
                targetPosition,
                4f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            touchingPlayer = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            touchingPlayer = false;
    }
}
```

https://streamable.com/mbevlw

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of Moving the platform using Vector3s, Create an animation that plays when the player enters a trigger zone.